# NSCoder Not Returning Values correctly

Tags: ios, nscoding

In the following code, the properties are never set correctly in the sharedInstance method, and I can't figure out why. It seems like I have the correct values though before I save it with the archiver.

```
  #import "User.h"

  static User *sharedInstance = nil;

  #define NAME @"name"
  #define USER_ID @"id"
  #define ACCOUNT_ID @"account_id"
  #define USER_NAME @"username"
  #define ADMIN @"admin"
  #define CURRENT_USER @"current_user"

  @implementation KSUser

  + (id)sharedInstance
  {
      @synchronized(self) {
          if (sharedInstance == nil) {
              NSData *userData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:CURRENT_USER];
              if (userData) {
                  sharedInstance = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:userData];
              }
              else {
                  sharedInstance = [[super alloc] init];
              }
          }
      }
      return sharedInstance;
  }

  - (void)populateFromJSON:(NSDictionary *)json
  {
      sharedInstance.name = json[NAME];
      sharedInstance.accountId = json[ACCOUNT_ID];
      sharedInstance.userId = json[USER_ID];
      sharedInstance.userName = json[USER_NAME];
      sharedInstance.admin = [json[ADMIN] boolValue];
      sharedInstance.loggedIn = YES;
      NSLog(@"values are: name: %@, %@, %@, %@", sharedInstance.name, sharedInstance.accountId, sharedInstance.userId, sharedInstance.userName);
  }

  - (void)logout
  {
      sharedInstance.name = nil;
      sharedInstance.accountId = nil;
      sharedInstance.userId = nil;
      sharedInstance.userName = nil;
      sharedInstance.admin = NO;
      sharedInstance.loggedIn = NO;
      [self saveState];

  }

  - (void)saveState
  {
      NSLog(@"values are: name: %@, %@, %@, %@", sharedInstance.name, sharedInstance.accountId, sharedInstance.userId, sharedInstance.userName);
      NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:sharedInstance];
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:CURRENT_USER];
  }

  - (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
  {
      [aCoder encodeObject:sharedInstance.userId forKey:USER_ID];
      [aCoder encodeObject:sharedInstance.accountId forKey:ACCOUNT_ID];
      [aCoder encodeObject:sharedInstance.name forKey:NAME];
      [aCoder encodeObject:sharedInstance.userName forKey:USER_NAME];
      [aCoder encodeBool:sharedInstance.admin forKey:ADMIN];
  }

  - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
  {
      if (self = [super init]) {
          sharedInstance.userId = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:USER_ID];
          sharedInstance.accountId = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:ACCOUNT_ID];
          sharedInstance.name = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:NAME];
          sharedInstance.userName = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:USER_NAME];
          sharedInstance.admin = [aDecoder decodeBoolForKey:ADMIN];
      }
      return self;
  }

  @end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is because your global variable sharedinstance in method - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder is always nil

Comment: You're right about that, but actually when I'm examining the values coming out of the decoder in initWithCoder, I get this:

po [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"user_id"]
(id) $1 = 0x00000000 <nil>

Comment: It is because you do not have such key @"user_id".

Comment: I do not see that you put something under the key @"user_id". I see only key @"id" that is stored in variable USER_ID

Comment: Oh yeah. Changed that:

(lldb) po [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"id"]
(id) $1 = 0x00000000 <nil>
(lldb) po [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"logged_in"]
(id) $2 = 0x00000000 <nil>
(lldb) po [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"account_id"]
(id) $3 = 0x00000000 <nil>

Comment: They all come back nil. It's weird.

Comment: Also here is the plist file:


// !!! BINARY PROPERTY LIST WARNING !!!
//
// The pretty-printed property list below has been created
// from a binary version on disk and should not be saved as
// the ASCII format is a subset of the binary representation!
//
{ EGORefreshTableView_LastRefresh = "Last Updated: 12/1/12, 12:26 PM";
 current_user = <62706C69 73743030 D4010203 0405081E 1F542474 6F705824 6F626A65 63747358 24766572 73696F6E 59246172 63686976 6572D106 0754726F 6F748001....

Comment: I've found that if your method `- (void)logout` is later than `saveState` method that you said called from enother class, then `- (void)logout` will overwrite your values with nil.

Answer (score 2):

In `initWithCoder:` don't refer to the shared instance but rather `self` instead. At the time it's executing `sharedInstance` is nil.

Also, you only call `saveState` after logging out, so it only saves out the nil values.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. Someone above pointed out that about sharedInstance. I actually call the saveState method from another class, so I think it's persisting the values.